# why @Autowired can get FactoryBean type and Bean type?

Tags: spring, autowired

I have spring factory bean creation in .xml

```
 <bean id="tool" class="pojo.ToolFactory">
    <property name="factoryId" value="9090"/>
    <property name="toolId" value="1"/>
 </bean>
```

and the `ToolFactory` code like this, which implements `FactoryBean` and create Tool bean:

```
public class ToolFactory implements FactoryBean<Tool> {

private int factoryId;
private int toolId;

public ToolFactory() {
}

public ToolFactory(int factoryId, int toolId) {
    this.factoryId = factoryId;
    this.toolId = toolId;
}

@Override
public Tool getObject() throws Exception {
    return new Tool(toolId);
}

@Override
public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return Tool.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {
    return false;
}

public int getFactoryId() {
    return factoryId;
}

public void setFactoryId(int factoryId) {
    this.factoryId = factoryId;
}

public int getToolId() {
    return toolId;
}

public void setToolId(int toolId) {
    this.toolId = toolId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ToolFactory{" +
            "factoryId=" + factoryId +
            ", toolId=" + toolId +
            '}';
}
```

}

when i use `@Autowired` to get bean with name of "tool", whose type could be `Tool`, which is not odd, but when i set the bean with type of `ToolFactory`, it can also be compiled and run correctly, then i am confused, could anyone give me an explanation? thanks~

here is the `@Autowired` code:

```
@Autowired
private Tool tool; //i can understand this

 @Autowired
private ToolFactory tool; // but  this can be compiled and run correctly, which is confused
```

and then when i use `@Autowired` with `@Qualifier`, the `Tool` or `ToolFactory` type could be also recognized:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("tool")
private Tool tool;

 @Autowired
@Qualifier("tool")
private ToolFactory tool;
```

why the bean with name "tool" could be Tool or ToolFactory type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sample auto wiring is done by type and the name matters not. The field could even be named `foo` and it would still work. The field name has nothing to do with the name of the bean you are looking for.

When it comes to auto wiring by type the `FactoryBean` is a bit special as you can either inject the `FactoryBean` itself or the type it generates. Spring will detect the type of field and either finds a direct bean of that type or a provider of that type (in this case the `FactoryBean`).

Now the `@Qualifier` isn't necessarily tied to the name. A qualifier can even be a different annotation etc. it can be anything. The name is used as a qualifier, however types generated from a `FactoryBean` (partially) inherit the same qualifiers as the factories providing them. That is the only way to specify qualifiers, apart from a custom qualifying annotation on the generated type.

So that is why both samples for auto wiring will work.

Comment: thanks a lot!  i thought ```@Autowired```  with ```@Qualifier``` will inject the bean by name, which is wrong. the qualifier will make difference when  there is ambiguous bean type, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it will, however again `@FactoryBean` is a bit special as it could match either one.